# Next.js catch-all dynamic routing not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, markdown, markdoc

I am struggling with implementing nextjs dynamic route for my static documentation page.

My current project structure is like so.

```
.
├── pages
    ├── docs
        ├── [...slug].tsx <- want to route here other than `/docs`
        ├── index.tsx     <- want to route here only `/docs`
│   ├── _app.tsx
│   └── index.tsx
└── next.config.js
```

For example, user arriving `https//:example.com/docs` will be routed to `docs/index.tsx` page and user arriving `https//:example.com/docs/something` will be routed to `docs/[...slug].tsx` page.

I use [...slug].tsx because I want to handle all routes under the `/docs/` with the same logic. So, `/docs/ABCD` and `/docs/ABCD/1234/` will be handled by [...slug].tsx.

Let say I have `Link` component in index.tsx like below.

```js
// `doc.slug` can be "ABCD" or "ABCD/1234"
const Docs = (props) => {
    const { docs } = props
    return (
        <div>
            {docs.map((doc, i) => {
                return (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <Link href={'/docs/' + doc.slug}>
                            <h1>GO</h1>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
```

And then in my `[...slug].tsx`.

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    // Our Markdown files are stored in the docs/ directory
    const DOCS_DIR = path.join(`${process.cwd() + '/src'}`, 'docs')

    // Find all Markdown files in the posts/ directory
    const docPaths = await glob(path.join(DOCS_DIR, '**/*.md'))

    // For each filename, the slug is the filename without the .md extension
    // and we split path which we use for our slug
    const paths = docPaths.map((docPath) => {
        const slug = docPath.split('docs/')[1].replace('.md', '')
        
        // We should have "ABCD" and "ABCD/1234" for our staticPath
        return { params: { slug: [slug] } } <- I think I do some wrong thing here?
    })

    // Return the possible paths
    return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

Current code works for single `docs/ABCD` route but returns 404 error in `docs/EFGH/1234` route (nested one).

So I tried to add some new route for handling nested route like below and it actually worked.

```
.
├── pages
    ├── docs
        ├── [EFGH]
            ├── 1234.tsx <- It works!
        ├── [...slug].tsx <- want to route here other than `/docs`
        ├── index.tsx     <- want to route here only `/docs`
│   ├── _app.tsx
│   └── index.tsx
└── next.config.js
```

It means the current dynamic route is not working correctly - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You were right, something wrong on the array.
It should return like this.

```
return { params: { slug: ['ABCD','1234'] } }
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#paths

Comment: My current code seems returning correctly in array. Do you see any problem here?

Comment: When I console.log to the `paths` parameter, it prints out `[{"params":{"slug":["ABCD"]}},{"params":{"slug":["EFGH/`1234"]}}]` so it seems working...